# How to use dayjs relative time

Tags: momentjs, dayjs

Hi guys I have this weird problem when using Dayjs relative time

Previously I use momentjs

```
var date = "2021-02-26 16:04:15";
moment(date).fromNow();
```

The relative time will always increase as expected

```
20 minutes ago, then increase to 21 minutes ago, then increase to 22 minutes ago
```

However when I use dayjs, the relative time is not increase. It works on page load, but never increase

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime';

var date = "2021-02-26 16:04:15";
dayjs(date).fromNow();
```

Output

```
20 minutes ago, and never increase. Just static
```

Is there any configuration that I miss or dayjs doesnt provide auto update on relative time?

Comment: are you running this in a loop or something?

Comment: @DanCantir sorry if the output make you confuse. Updated

Comment: How do you know it doesn't increase?  I guess we need more code. Also, are you using `dayjs.extend(relativeTime)` to extend dayjs?

Answer (score 0):

After my research, I believe Day Js does not have auto increment relative time, as compare to MomentJS

So I just need to use setTimeout to auto emit event every 60 seconds contains the latest timestamp.

And all place that need relative time will be notify to update the state

Example in Vue JS

**app.js**

```
created() {

    let self = this;

    this.timer = setInterval(function () { self.$eventBus.$emit("updateTimeLabel", new Date()); }, 60000);

},
beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
}
```

**TimeLabel.vue**

```
props: {
    timestamp: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
},
data() {
    return {
      from_now: null,
    };
},
created() {
    this.from_now = this.$fromNow(this.timestamp);

    // every one minute, app.js will emit event to update all TimeLabel.vue relative time

    this.$eventBus.$on("updateTimeLabel", (datetime) => {
      this.from_now = this.$fromNow(this.timestamp);
    });
},
methods: {

    $fromNow(timestamp) {
      return dayjs.utc(timestamp.substring(0, 23)).local().fromNow();
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dan said you have to import not only dayjs and relativeTime, but also extend dayjs with relativeTime plugin.

```
// import dayjs
import dayjs from "dayjs";

// import relativeTime plugin
import relativeTime from "dayjs/plugin/relativeTime"; 

// extend dayjs with relativeTime plugin
dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
```

After that, you can use it as shown in the docs https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/relative-time

Answer (score 0):

1. pnpm add dayjs / npm install dayjs / yarn add dayjs
2. add this line to import dayjs to your file: import dayjs from 'dayjs';
3. add this line to import relative time to your file import relativeTime from "dayjs/plugin/relativeTime";  (no need for extra installation)
4. add this line under your imports dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
5. You should now be able to use the fromNow function like so:{dayjs(post.createdAt.toISOString()).fromNow()}